# NSNumber acting as an optional even though it not declared as one

Tags: swift

I have a number I am storing inside a swift dictionary. I am using NSNumber since I must serialize to JSON. I'm confused as to why the 5th line below down not work and the 6th does. The `currentCt` seems to think it is an optional, however, on line 1 it is not declared as an optional a in `Dictionary<String, NSNumber>()` Any thoughts as to why?

Also, I am not sure why bridging does not allow the Int and NSNumber to be automatically added and I must resort to using Int(currentCt!) . Again, any thoughts are much appreciated.

```
var activeMinDic = Dictionary<String, NSNumber>()
activeMinDic["1"] = 5
var currentCt = activeMinDic[String(1)]
activeMinDic[String(1)] = 1 + 1 // works fine
activeMinDic[String(1)] = 1 + currentCt // does not work
activeMinDic[String(1)] = 1 + Int(currentCt!) // works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are hitting is not specific to `NSNumber`.  It’s that that Swift dictionaries return an optional, because they key might not be present in the dictionary.

So this line:

```
var currentCt = activeMinDic[String(1)]
```

is shorthand for this:

```
var currentCt: NSNumber? = activeMinDic[String(1)]
```

You have to unwrap the return value from the key fetching in some fashion, such as:

```
// default to an NSNumber of 0 if not present
let currentCt = activeMinDic[String(1)] ?? 0

// or require it:
if let currentCt = activeMinDic[String(1)] {
    // use currentCt
}
else {
    // handle currentCt not being present
}
```

Re the bridging – there isn’t an implicit conversion from `NSNumber` to other numeric types.  In fact there isn’t even a `+` for two `NSNumbers`.  Bear in mind, an `NSNumber` can contain various different kinds of numeric representation, which you extract with `.floatValue`, `.integerValue` etc.  Swift as a language is quite strict (unlike some other C-like languages) in not implicitly converting between different types (avoiding all the associated problems of implicit truncation etc) so it’s not surprising you need to explicitly state the numeric to extract (with `.integerValue`, `as Int`, or with `Int`’s `init` as you’re doing here).

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your dictionary as [Int: NSNumber], this way you can use an Int as the Key and use if let to unwrap your dictionary values. Take a look:

```
var activeMinDic:[Int: NSNumber] = [:]
activeMinDic[1] = 5

if let currentCt = activeMinDic[1] as? Int {
    println(currentCt)
    activeMinDic[currentCt] = 1 + 1 // works fine
    activeMinDic[currentCt] = 1 + currentCt
}
```

Comment: “You should declare your dictionary as [NSObject:AnyObject], this way you can use an Int as the Key and use if let to unwrap your dictionary values.”  No, you really shouldn’t.  Especially the latter part – `AnyObject` doesn’t give you a special ability to use `if let` in that way any more than using `NSNumber` does.

Comment: Ok i should just use  NsNumber.  i am just showing how to do it in a general approach. you saw my comment saying that the problem was that the array could have an item or not at the index and that's why it was returning an optional.

Comment: Or maybe [Int:NSNumber]

Comment: That String(1) makes no sense specially when trying to use it as an index

Comment: I agree `String(1)` is silly but the solution to this is not to toss the types out of the window.  Especially since it will likely lead to immense confusion: `var d: [NSObject:Int] = [:]; d["1"] = 1; d[1] = 1; d.count // returns 2`

Comment: As I said [Int:NSNumber] would be the best approach. I will edit

Comment: I only choose NSObject because he was already using strings as the keys. I was just giving him an option to have any object as the key also.

Comment: First, thanks for the answers and pointing out the errors in my ways.  Unfortunately, I didn't give all the background info. The reason I'm using a string as the Key is because I am serializing to json, and json keys and numbers don't play nice. If I'm incorrect in that , please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is of type `[String:NSNumber]`, but the method `subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set}` does return an optional. You will better know the `subscript()` method by the overloaded `[]` operator.